# Use macro in excel 2010 to copy values into a cell from the cell directly above it

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a Row of drop down lists and I am trying to make a macro so that if that row is entirely filled in I could highlight the cells beneath that row, then run the macro and have it fill in those highlighted cells with the value from the previous row's cells.

Here is my code so far, its quite simple but every time I run it I get a Run Time error '13' type mismatch.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Application.Selection = 1 Then      'This line is the problem
Exit Sub
ElseIf Application.Selection > 1 Then       'This line is also a problem
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pare this back to shorter code to work only on the blank cells that exist in the `Selection`.

If the `Selection` is invalid, or if there are no blank cells, the code simply ends given the error handling

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Resume Next
If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for cells when more than one cell is selected, but if one cell is selected the rest of the cells are filled with a reference value error. Even the one cell that was selected returns a reference value error. Which is the reason i am asking this question in the first place. Thank you for the quick response though.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, I've been googling for close to 4 hours and found nothing helpful. So, thanks again.